# Retrieve the window name and role

Tags: window-manager, desktop-environment, window, eclipse

I'm running Eclipse and I detached some of the windows. Now I have 4 windows linked to Eclipse. What I need is to be able to identify each individual window and be able to control it.

If I run tools like: `xprop`, `xwininfo`, or `wmctrl -l` I can retrieve the `WM_CLASS` and `WM_NAME` for the main window but I can't get them for the other 3 child windows.

How can I retrieve the `WM_NAME` and `WM_ROLE` for all 4 windows?

Comment: Does X require every window to have those attributes? If you don't see them when running xprop on them then it may be the case that they're just missing for those windows.

Comment: @JosephGarvin I needed those in order to be able to position the windows in the places I wanted to instead of where they get dumped by default.

Answer (score 3):

In searching for an answer to your question I ran across this very in depth [article on window matching](http://wiki.compiz.org/WindowMatching/) that could be very helpful.  You may find that Eclipse is to blame for not following the correct naming standards in generating the child windows making this a bug for which you should [request a fix from the developers](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/Getting_Involved#Testing_and_Bug_Filing).

Comment: I've used your guidance to further my research, but the question still stands. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Using [Intrinsics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsics) can solve your problem of getting WM_WINDOW_ROLE and WM_NAME.

Comment: for people who down voted [C language interface index of Intrinsics](http://www.x.org/docs/Xt/intr.idx.pdf)